# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - Access project file inside my Meteor app from inappbrowser

Tags: cordova, meteor, reactjs, inappbrowser

Im new in Meteor and React, building my first app for **Android** with it (I was on Angular1).

This app have many little games inside, I'm trying to serve those games from my *resources/* folder.

My problem is: when I click in a title, an inappbrowser windows pop-up, and I want to serve my game there.

I've tried many ways to open a file inside `resources/games/meme/index.html` but I always get: **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** or **net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** (this last one when I used `file:///games/meme/index.html`)

This is my code:

```
// here I have some settings
const inAppOptions = 'location=no,clearcache=yes,toolbar=no';
const target = '_blank';

// and here the code itself
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        let ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('file:///games/meme/index.html', target, inAppOptions);
        ref.addEventListener('exit', () => cordova.InAppBrowser.close());
    });
}
```

So far, I've tried the `let ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('file:///games/meme/index.html', target, inAppOptions);` line with:
`'file:///games/meme/index.html'`
`'/games/meme/index.html'`
`'/resources/games/meme/index.html'`
`'resources/games/meme/index.html'`

**And I've also placed the games/ folder and its contents inside the public/ directory, same result.**

I have the cordova-whitelist plugin installed, and the `App.accessRule('*', {type: 'navigation'});` inside the `mobile-config.js`.

This is my folder structure:

```
MyApp
├── .meteor
├── client
├── imports
├── node_modules
├── public
│   ├── games
│   │   ├── meme
│   │   │   ├── index.html
│   ├── img
├── resources
│   ├── games
│   │   ├── meme
│   │   │   ├── index.html
│   ├── icons
│   ├── splash
├── server
│   mobile-config.js
│   package.json
```

I hope someone can help me, I didn't had this problem with ionic in angular, where the root folder is where I was, so I had to navigate like this: `'../../resources/games/meme/index.html'` to get to the file.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I tried to write the address manually in the chrome://inspect, and accessed successfully like this: localhost:12200/games/meme/index.html (this is on public/ folder), but I couldn't with the same address in the inappbrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just speculation here but I know that when developing for Android using React Native I can't use `localhost` as it fails to resolve. Try swapping out `localhost` for you're machine's IP address.

Comment: Thanks Spencer!, we decided to include this second app in the meteor project directly, that means: **access to it with regular routes, without inappbrowser**. It's easier and we don't have to deal with this kind of issues. I'm gonna tag this as correct since I belive this was my problem too. Thanks for your help!